# Align logotype to centre, but not the tm symbol

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need to centrally align a logotype to packaging, but I do not want the (C) to be aligned, but I want it still to be grouped as it will be used on various sizes of packaging and I do not want to adjust manually each time as it needs to be consistent.
I've tried a rectangle and keying it to that, but that doesn't help as I have the same issue when aligning to the packaging cutter guide.
So, everything in blue needs to be aligned centrally to the packaging - but NOT the *BY (C)* in red, but I still want this all to be grouped. The dimension just a guide.
Any ideas?[image]

Comment: Can't you just group it with an invisible rectangle with no stroke or fill? [see example](https://imgur.com/EM5LO2H).

Comment: @BillyKerr 's suggestion is *exactly* how I handle this.. I put a "hollow" rectangle on the opposite side which matches the width of any ™ or ® or © (Logos don't traditionally have a © notice though, ™ or ® are more likely.)

Comment: When they print the packaging in real life, on real cardboard, you can pretty much expect the 25mm margins to be slightly shifted, so this is also a bit relative.

Comment: Thanks guys, but no.

Comment: Today, the packaging file might be 50mm wide, but tomorrow it could be a 6ft banner so I need the distance between the *By (C)* to be consistent every time so using another rectangle and keying it to that would still align the whole group to the centre of the artboard/packaging/banner. The LogoType needs to be in the centre every time with the *By (C)* in the same position - every time, but not centred as a group; but still part of the group. Make sense? Clear as mud :( The image was just a visual guide - no problems with bleed.

Comment: I've figured it out. I created a rectangle, aligned it to the centre of the artboard, then, with the logotype grouped, I keyed it/aligned it to the LEFT of the new rectangle. hold shift when enlarging from the centre. The LogoType will be perfectly in the middle and the (C) will still be grouped, but not in the centre. Thanks for the help y'all.